# How to import CSS and JS files in Node.js without using view engines?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I recently started learning node.js and now I'm stuck.  am now building a basic authentication webpage including Login and Register. The `res.sendfile` method is not importing CSS files. I did not opt for view engines as I find it a bit difficult and messy. Is there any way to import CSS files here? Here is my code. Excuse me if I've kept it too long, as it is my first time asking a question here.

This is my login GET route where I've used `res.sendFile`.

```js
login.get("/",(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/auth', 'login.html'));
})
```

Comment: add your css and js files directly to html file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is that it is not serving the files in the desired directory.
Try adding this in the line above so it looks like this:

```
app.use(express.static("client/build"));

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
})
```

I guess `login` and in the example I've provided above I chaged it to something more standard as `app` is the variable you've called express after init it. Send the whole nodeJS server-file otherwise.

Don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you very much. As a matter of fact, I do have a few other questions. Can I get your email or some other mode of contact, it it isn't a problem for you?

Comment: @Pratapsimha Consider posting your questions on Stack Overflow, so all can benefit from the questions and answers.

Comment: @DennisHadzialic If you're using `express.static()` in this way, there should be no need for the specific handler for `index.html`, as that's already included by Express.

Comment: @DennisHadzialic, it didn't work as well. CSS is not at all imported. I tried express.static(path.join(__dirname,  "client")), and it worked. But, the same won't work when it's inside a route,i.e, app.get("/")

Comment: @Pratapsimha Do you have a Github-repository to share so I can take a deeper look?

Comment: @DennisHazialic, no I don't..but I will create one and let you know.